# Open an X window and get/set its ID?

Tags: window, x11, xorg

Essentially, I want to from the commandline start an application and have a way to store that ID for later use so I can manipulate that window with say wmctrl. Something like this

```
 openandgetID "vlc" > ~/.IDofVLC
```

So I can always read this file to get the numeric ID of the window it is in so that I can manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is not possible. However, well behaved clients set `_NET_WM_PID` property for it's windows so once you get your process pid you can wait until main window is created and traverse all window tree checking each window `_NET_WM_PID` property.

Also you can leverage [startup notification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/startup-notification-spec/startup-notification-latest.txt) protocol - in short, some clients may broadcast ClientMessage (send it to root, but you can listen for them as well) with startup notification-encoded payload which includes pid and startup status.